# How change the regexp to find www.something.com?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here, I have a regexp which will find the urls. But, my regexp is finding the urls which has `http` now, how I can find `www.something.com` as well.
my regexp is `(^|\s)((?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,}))\.?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[\/?#]\S*)?)gi`
With I need to find `www.something.com` as url.

Comment: Your pattern contains errors.

Comment: Now, it is fine

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the regex part which is responsible for matching protocol:

```
(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)
```

Comment: If i remove https and ftp how I can whether it is url or not.